# Is it possible to prefill an Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am currently working on a Excel file which is gathering products, their [EAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number) and some other datas. I was wondering if there is feature inside Excel to prefill the cells that contain the EAN with the prefixe so when I click the cell, I just have to enter the last digits of the code. I know I can enter the prefixe and then I have to move the cursor to the end when I want the digits, but that is not really convenient.

I have thought of using VBA (something like if there is a cell change with some digits string in this column, it will modify it to the real EAN, else it will erase it) but if there is already something that can do it on Excel, why not using it.

[image: Here is the example as requested.]

We are supposing that the prefix is 12345678 and I want to enter only the last 5 digits part. What I am asking is if there is a way to prefill the cells below, so when I click or select the cell via tab or enter, I only need to enter the 5 last digits, I don't need to click another time on the textbox to place my cursor at the end.

Comment: An example could be helpful.

Comment: I have added it on the edit.

Comment: If you only need to display the full number, not actually use it (or compare it in a lookup), you can make the prefix part of the number format.  Only the last digits would actually be stored in the cell, but the prefix would be included in the display.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved, I have answered it myself and will close the question when I can accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fixer1234** method is what I was looking for, I have created a custom format using cells formating.

In my example, the prefixe was 12345678 and I was looking for 5 digits, so the format was :

> "12345678" 00000

**"12345678"** is the prefixe, between quotes to consider it as a string.

**00000** is the five digits code, I used **#####** in the beginning, but when there was some zeros in the left of the code, they were not displayed.

So if I want to display 1234567800045 in a cell, I just place 45.

---

If you want to use the full value and not what is displayed for some reason, look at **jc bermu**'s answer using VBA.

But be careful about running macros on a XL file, you need to enable macros because of security reason and sending the file via e-mail might considered as junk mail.

Answer (score 0):

This Macro is a good starting point:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    eancolumn = 1
    Prefix = "1234"
    therow = Target.Row
    thecolumn = Target.Column
    If eancolumn = thecolumn Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
                Target = Prefix & Target.Value
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Open Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, double click *Sheet1* in the left side and paste the code on the right side. This code is then executed in `Sheet 1` everytime there is a change. The variable `eancolumn` determines on which column will be added the prefix.